# How to access javascript function html page arguments?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a page that updates without reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168383/creating-a-page-that-updates-without-reloading)

I want to get the content of an HTML page from it's URL and put it somehwere in the current document. The pseudo-code below shows the approach I want to take:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="text"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getPageText(htmlPage)
{
   //comment: How do I get innerHTML?
   var text = htmlPage.body.innerHTML;

   //comment: How do I have to return?    
   return text;
}


document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=getPageText("https://google.com");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please explain your question more in detail

Comment: i think you want to know how the javascript function called from the html page?? m i right??

Comment: yes, https_://www.google_com (arguments) is not the current page.
i send a other htmlPage to method. 
and I want get this htmlPage load html sourcecode.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the technique you are looking for is AJAX --- You need to download the remote page (and it has to allow you to) in order for javascript to get the content of the page.

see another answer for an overview of that technique --- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168402/473914

Answer (score 1):

you need to extract content from google and then you could use innerHtml. Alternatively you  can use iframe  and wrap scr dynamically or statically. code for wraping scr dynamically is as follow.

***a.html***

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script>
      function getPageText(url){
          document.getElementById("container").setAttribute("src",url); 
      }
      getPageText("https://www.google.com");
   </script>
 </head>

 <body>
   <iframe id='container'></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```